# Why is matter-antimatter asymmetry surprising, if asymmetry can be generated by a random walk in which particles go into black holes?

Tags: black-holes, antimatter, hawking-radiation, baryogenesis

My understanding is the early universe was a very "hot" (ie energy dense) environment. It was even hot enough for black holes to [form from photons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kugelblitz_%28astrophysics%29).

My second point of understanding is that black holes can lose mass due to hawking radiation, [which amounts to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation):

> Physical insight into the process may be gained by imagining that
>   particle–antiparticle radiation is emitted from just beyond the event
>   horizon. This radiation does not come directly from the black hole
>   itself, but rather is a result of virtual particles being "boosted" by
>   the black hole's gravitation into becoming real particles.[citation
>   needed] As the particle–antiparticle pair was produced by the black
>   hole's gravitational energy, the escape of one of the particles lowers
>   the mass of the black hole.[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryogenesis#GUT_Baryogenesis_under_Sakharov_conditions)
>
> An alternative view of the process is that vacuum fluctuations cause a
>   particle–antiparticle pair to appear close to the event horizon of a
>   black hole. One of the pair falls into the black hole while the other
>   escapes. In order to preserve total energy, the particle that fell
>   into the black hole must have had a negative energy (with respect to
>   an observer far away from the black hole). This causes the black hole
>   to lose mass, and, to an outside observer, it would appear that the
>   black hole has just emitted a particle. In another model, the process
>   is a quantum tunnelling effect, whereby particle–antiparticle pairs
>   will form from the vacuum, and one will tunnel outside the event
>   horizon.

So I simulated a scenario with two types of particles that are created in a 50/50 ratio from hawking radiation, and always annihilate each other if possible.

> **Edit:**
>
> In this simulation both particles are created, but one gets sucked
>   into the black hole. The other stays outside. So the charge should be
>   conserved.

The simulation (written in R) is here:

```
# Run the simulation for 1 million steps and initialize output matrix
n_steps = 1e6
res     = matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = n_steps)

# Initiate number of particles to zero
n0 = n1 = 0
for(i in 1:n_steps){
  # Generate a new particle with 50/50 chance of matter/antimatter
  x = sample(0:1, 1)

  # If "x" is a matter particle then...
  if(x == 0){
    # If an antimatter particle exists, then annihilate it with the new matter particle. 
    #Otherwise increase the number of matter particles by one
    if(n1 > 0){
      n1 = n1 - 1
    }else{
      n0 = n0 + 1
    }
  }

  # If "x" is an antimatter particle then...
  if(x == 1){
    # If a matter particle exists, then annihilate it with the new antimatter particle. 
    # Otherwise increase the number of antimatter particles by one
    if(n0 > 0){
      n0 = n0 - 1
    }else{
      n1 = n1 + 1
    }
  }

  # Save the results and plot them if "i" is a multiple of 1000
  res[i, ] = c(n0, n1)
  if(i %% 1000 == 0){
    plot(res[1:i, 1], ylim = range(res[1:i, ]), type = "l", lwd = 3, panel.first = grid())
    lines(res[1:i, 2], col = "Red", lwd = 3)
  }
}
```

Here is a snapshot of the results, where the black line is the number of "type 0" particles and the red line is the number of "type 1" particles:
[image]

Obviously this is a simplified 1d model where any generated anti-matter is immediately annihilated by a corresponding particle of matter, etc. However, I do not see why the qualitative result of a dominant particle "species" would not be expected to hold in general. So what is the basis for expecting equal amounts of matter and antimatter? How is it in conflict with this simple simulation?

**EDIT:**

As requested in the comments I modified the simulation to allow different initial number of particles and the probability of generating each particle.

```
# Run the simulation for 1 million steps and initialize output matrix
n_steps = 250e3
res     = matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = n_steps)

# Initial number of each type of particle and probability of generating type 0
n0 = 0
n1 = 0
p0 = 0.51
for(i in 1:n_steps){
  # Generate a new particle with 50/50 chance of matter/antimatter
  x = sample(0:1, 1, prob = c(p0, 1 - p0))

  # If "x" is a matter particle then...
  if(x == 0){
    # If an antimatter particle exists, then annihilate it with the new matter particle. 
    # Otherwise increase the number of matter particles by one
    if(n1 > 0){
      n1 = n1 - 1
    }else{
      n0 = n0 + 1
    }
  }

  # If "x" is an antimatter particle then...
  if(x == 1){
    # If a matter particle exists, then annihilate it with the new antimatter particle. 
    # Otherwise increase the number of antimatter particles by one
    if(n0 > 0){
      n0 = n0 - 1
    }else{
      n1 = n1 + 1
    }
  }

  # Save the results and plot them if "i" is a multiple of 1000
  res[i, ] = c(n0, n1)
  if(i %% 1e4 == 0){
    plot(res[1:i, 1], ylim = range(res[1:i, ]), type = "l", lwd = 3, panel.first = grid())
    lines(res[1:i, 2], col = "Red", lwd = 3)
  }
}
```

Some examples:

n0 = 1000, n1 = 0, p = 0.5
[image]

n0 = 0, n1 = 0, p = 0.51
[image]

n0 = 1000, n1 = 1000, p = 0.5
[image]

**EDIT 2:**

Thanks all for your answers and comments. I learned the name for the process of generating matter from black holes is "black hole baryogenesis". However, in the papers I checked on this topic (eg [Nagatani 1998](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9805455), [Majumdar et al 1994](https://doi.org/10.1142/S0218271895000363)) do not seem to be talking about the same thing I am.

I am saying that via the dynamics of symmetric generation and annihilation of matter-antimatter along with symmetric baryogenesis via hawking radiation you will **always** get an imbalance over time that will tend to grow due to a positive feedback. Ie, the [Sakharov conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryogenesis#GUT_Baryogenesis_under_Sakharov_conditions) such as CP-violation are **not** actually required to get an asymmetry.

If you accept pair-production, annihilation, and hawking radiation exists, then you should by default expect one dominant species of particle to dominate over the other at all times. That is the only stable state (besides an energy-only universe). Approximately equal matter/antimatter is quite obviously very unstable because they annihilate each other, so it makes no sense to expect that.

It is possible that in some more complicated model (including more than one type of particle-pair, distance between particles, forces, etc) somehow this tendency towards asymmetry would be somehow canceled out. But I cannot think of any reason why that would be, it should be up to the people who expect matter-antimatter symmetry to come up with a mechanism to explain that (which would be an odd thing to spend your time on since that is decidedly not what we observe in our universe).

Regarding some specific issues people had:

1) Concerns about negative charge accumulating in the black holes and positive charge accumulating in the regular space

- While in the simulation there is only one particle, in practice this would be happening in parallel for electron-positrons and proton-antiproton pairs at (afaik) equal rates. So I would not expect any kind of charge imbalance. You can imagine particle pairs in the simulation are half electron-positrons and half proton-antiprotons.

2) There were not enough black holes in the early universe to explain the asymmetry

- I tried and failed to get an exact quote for this so I could figure out what assumptions were made, but I doubt they included the positive feedback shown by the simulation in their analysis. Also, I wondered if they considered the possibility of kugelblitz black holes forming in an energy-only universe. Finally, the tendency towards a dominant species is ongoing all the time, it need not to have happened in the early universe anyway.

3) If this process is ongoing in a universe that looks like ours today (where it may take a long time for a particle to travel from one black hole to the other), we would expect some black holes to locally happen to generate antimatter dominated regions and others to generate matter dominated regions. Eventually some of these regions should come into contact with each other leading to an observable mass annihilation of particles.

- I agree this would be the default expectation, but If you start from a highly matter-dominated state it would be very unlikely for enough antimatter to be generated to locally annihilate all the matter and even then there is only a 50% chance the next phase is antimatter. Putting numbers on stuff like this would require a more complex model that I don't wish to attempt here.

4) Asymmetry is not actually considered surprising by physicists.

- Well, it says this [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon_asymmetry):

  > Neither the standard model of particle physics, nor the theory of
  >   general relativity provides a known explanation for why this should be
  >   so, and it is a natural assumption that the universe be neutral with
  >   all conserved charges. [...] As remarked in a 2012 research paper,
  >   "The origin of matter remains one of the great mysteries in physics."

5) This process is somehow an exotic "alternative" theory to the standard.

- This process was deduced by accepting standard physics/cosmology to be correct. It is a straightforward consequence of the interplay between pair production/annihilation and hawking radiation. It may seem counterintuitive to people used to thinking about what we would expect *on average* from a model, when actually we want to think about how the individual instances behave. If the simulation is run multiple times and add up all the "particles" the result will be ~50/50 matter/antimatter. However, we observe one particular universe not an average of all possible universes. In each particular instance there is always a dominating species of particle, which we end up calling "matter".

So, after reading the answers/comments **I think the answer to my question is probably that physicists were thinking of what they would expect on average when they should have been thinking about what would happen in specific instances.** But I'm not familiar enough with the literature to say.

**Edit 3:**

After talking with Chris in the chat I decided to make the rate of annihilation dependent on the number of particles in the universe. I did this by setting the probability of annihilation to exp(-100/n_part), where n_part is the number of particles. This was pretty arbitrary, I chose it to have decent coverage over the whole typical range for 250k steps. It looks like this:
[image]

Here is the code (I also added some parallelization, sorry for the increased complexity):

```
require(doParallel)

# Number of simulations to run and threads to use in parallel
n_sim   = 100
n_cores = 30

# Initial number of each type of particle and probability
n0 = 0
n1 = 0
p0 = 0.5

registerDoParallel(cores = n_cores)
out = foreach(sim = 1:n_sim) %dopar% {
  # Run the simulation for 250k steps and initialize output matrix
  n_steps = 250e3
  res     = matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = n_steps)

  for(i in 1:n_steps){
    # Generate a new particle with 50/50 chance of matter/antimatter
    x = sample(0:1, 1, prob = c(p0, 1 - p0))

    n_part = sum(res[i -1, ]) + 1
    p_ann  = exp(-100/n_part)
    flag   = sample(0:1, 1, prob = c(1 - p_ann, p_ann))


    # If "x" is a matter particle then...
    if(x == 0){
      # If an antimatter particle exists, then annihilate it with the new matter particle. 
      # Otherwise increase the number of matter particles by one
      if(n1 > 0 & flag){
        n1 = n1 - 1
      }else{
        n0 = n0 + 1
      }
    }

    # If "x" is an antimatter particle then...
    if(x == 1){
      # If a matter particle exists, then annihilate it with the new antimatter particle. 
      # Otherwise increase the number of antimatter particles by one
      if(n0 > 0 & flag){
        n0 = n0 - 1
      }else{
        n1 = n1 + 1
      }
    }

    # Save the results and plot them if "i" is a multiple of 1000
    res[i, ] = c(n0, n1)
    if(i %% 1e4 == 0 && sim %in% seq(1, n_sim, by = n_cores)){
      # plot(res[1:i, 1], ylim = range(res[1:i, ]), type = "l", lwd = 3, panel.first = grid())
      # lines(res[1:i, 2], col = "Red", lwd = 3)
      print(paste0(sim, ": ", i))
    }
  }
  return(res)
}
```

Here is an example of 25 results:
[image]

And a histogram of the percent of particles that were in the minor class by the end of each simulation:
[image]

So the results still agree with the simpler model in that such systems will tend to have a dominant species of particle.

**Edit 4:**

After further helpful conversation with chris he suggested that annihilation of more than one particle pair per step was the crucial added factor. Specifically that the number of removed particles should be a sample from the Poisson distribution with a mean proportional to the total number of particles, ie rpois(1, m*n0*n1) where m is small enough so that annihilation are very rare until a large number of matter and antimatter particles exist.

Here is the code (which is quite different from earlier):

```
require(doParallel)

# Number of simulations to run and threads to use in parallel
n_sim   = 100
n_cores = 30

# Initial number of each type of particle and probability
n0 = 0
n1 = 0
p0 = 0.5
m  = 10^-4

# Run the simulation for 250k steps and 
n_steps = 250e3

registerDoParallel(cores = n_cores)
out = foreach(sim = 1:n_sim) %dopar% {
  # Initialize output matrix
  res = matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = n_steps)

  for(i in 1:n_steps){
    # Generate a new particle with 50/50 chance of matter/antimatter
    x = sample(0:1, 1, prob = c(p0, 1 - p0))

    # If "x" is a matter particle then...
    if(x == 0){
      n0 = n0 + 1
    }

    # If "x" is an antimatter particle then...
    if(x == 1){
      n1 = n1 + 1
    }

    # Delete number of particles proportional to the product of n0*n1
    n_del = rpois(1, m*n0*n1)
    n0 = max(0, n0 - n_del)
    n1 = max(0, n1 - n_del)

    # Save the results and plot them if "i" is a multiple of 1000
    res[i, 1:2] = c(n0, n1)
    res[i, 3]   = min(res[i, 1:2])/sum(res[i, 1:2])
    if(i %% 1e4 == 0 && sim %in% seq(1, n_sim, by = n_cores)){
      # plot(res[1:i, 1], ylim = range(res[1:i, ]), type = "l", lwd = 3, panel.first = grid())
      # lines(res[1:i, 2], col = "Red", lwd = 3)
      print(paste0(sim, ": ", i))
    }
  }
  return(res)
}
```

And here are the results for various values of "m" (which controls how often annihilation occurs). This plot shows the average proportion of minor particles for each step (using 100 simulations per value of m) as the blue line, the green line is the median, and the bands are +/- 1 sd from the mean:

[image]

The first plot has the same behavior as my simulations, and you can see that as m gets smaller (annihilation rate as a function of number of particles becomes rarer) the system tends to stay in a more symmetric state (50/50 matter/antimatter), at least for more steps.

So **a key assumption made by physicists seems to be that the annihilation rate in the early universe was very low, so that enough particles could accumulate until they became common enough that neither is likely to ever get totally "wiped out".**

EDIT 5:

I ran one of those Poisson simulations for 8 million steps with m = 10^-6 and you can see that it just takes longer for the dominance to play out (it looks slightly different because the 1 sigma fill wouldn't plot with so many data points):
[image]

So from that I conclude the very low annihilation rates just delay how long it takes, rather than resulting in a fundamentally different outcome.

**Edit 6:**

Same thing happens with m = 10^-7 and 28 million steps. The aggregate chart looks the same as the above m = 10^-6 with 8 million steps. So here are some individual examples. You can see a clear trend towards a dominating species just as in the original model:
[image]

**Edit 7:**

To wrap this up... I think the answer to the question ("why do physicists think this?") is clear from my conversation with Chris [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99444/discussion-between-chris-and-livid). Chris does not seem interested in making that into an answer but I will accept it if someone writes similar.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99405/discussion-on-question-by-livid-why-is-matter-antimatter-asymmetry-surprising-i).

Comment: This example uses one type of particle/antiparticle. If it is charged,   proton/antiproton,  (which is your argument) then charge conservation and baryon number conservation are the same, which makes it is not physical If you look at the literature of "black hole baryogenesis" , extra assumptions are needed, model  ( GUTS or somehting else) dependent for the models to be predictive, not just random walks.

Comment: The above is true for a single black hole . There is no mechanism that ensures that for a statistical distribution of black holes it will be the same particle that will dominate the black hole. Statistics for two particles would say that it would be 50/50 , unless a model is used, and that is why the models are necessary.

Comment: @annav Basically I am trying to keep it simple because I think you should need to come up with a mechanism that _prevents_ a dominance between matter and anti-matter. It would not be difficult to add another set of particle pairs to this model, but I do not want to at this time. There are many other details of the calculation that are inconsistent with our universe already. The resuls are only qualitatively meaningful.

Comment: I am trying to say that random walk around one black hole  is not enough, as with many black holes  both protons and antiprotons may be absorbed with a 50/50 chance, and that  a physics model is needed that will introduce baryons and lead to baryon number violation

Comment: @annav This is in the comments that have been sent to chat but I was imagining this happened in the early universe when the distance between black holes could be approximated as negligible (matter generated by one could be quickly annihilated by antimatter generated by another to the point it could be considered instantaneous). However, that is hardly the only scenario.

Comment: @Livid The problem is, we have a decent idea of when this happened, even though we do not have all the details - when matter came to dominate (and both non-dark energy and anti-matter essentially disappeared), the universe was already humongous. In fact, our current best models expect that this wasn't an accident - the universe was essentially empty throughout inflation (no energy or matter), and it was the (speculative) inflaton field's collapse that released all the non-dark energy you see around you today. This is speculative, but with good math and corresponding to how QFT works.

Comment: @Luaan I want to emphasize that this guess about the early universe is not crucial to my point. As noted in my "edit 2" the positive feedback forcing an asymmetry in the simulation is a straightforward consequence of accepting pair production and hawking radiation. I mean fine, the universe was huge and then there were localized regions of matter and antimatter (but slightly more matter) and there was a period of annihilation long in the past that makes antimatter dominated regions very rare today. It makes more sense to me that this would happen immediately though.

Comment: @Livid Hawking radiation and pair production are unrelated. You're still assuming that a black hole simply creates either a positron or an electron at random, with 50% chance. There is no reason to believe that. Hawking radiation depends on the charge of the black hole, so if the black hole emits a 100 electrons in a row, there *is* a much bigger chance the next time is going to be a positron. It's not a *random* process, it's *probabilistic*. Tweak your simulation to account for this, and your asymmetry disappears. You still need something specifically prefering matter.

Comment: @Luaan I don't think "tweaking" the model to get exactly the right amount of matter-antimatter ratio to not allow one to dominate makes much sense. You are basically fine tuning it to *not* match reality. If the black hole needs to "emit" particles based on charge why not just as well have it emit an anti-proton instead of an electron? But see my conversation with Chris below.

Comment: @Luaan Check the latest edits. The key seems to be a low annihilation rate.

Comment: @Livid Because an anti-proton has much more mass than a positron, I've already mentioned that before. This means it needs much smaller black holes to be produced, and it's much rarer even then.

Comment: @Luaan Ok, as I mentioned earlier. My point is I expect the same qualitative result in a more complex detailed model. People keep coming up with things to add in and every time so far we have seen the same qualitative result. Why do you think different sized black holes will cancel out this effect? By what mechanism?

Answer (score 81):

Congratulations on finding a method for baryogenesis that works! Indeed, it's true that if you have a bunch of black holes, then by random chance you'll get an imbalance. And this imbalance will remain even after the black holes evaporate, because the result of the evaporation doesn't depend on the overall baryon number that went into the black hole.

Black holes can break conservation laws like that. The only conservation laws they can't break are the ones where you can measure the conserved quantity from outside. For example, charge is still conserved because you can keep track of the charge of the black hole by measuring its electric field. In the Standard Model, baryon number has no such associated field.

Also, you need to *assume* that enough black holes form to make your mechanism work. In the standard models, this doesn't happen, despite the high temperatures. If you start with a standard Big Bang, the universe expands too fast for black holes to form.

---

However, in physics, finding a mechanism that solves a problem isn't the end -- it's the beginning. We aren't all sitting around scratching our heads for *any* mechanism to achieve baryogenesis. There are actually at least ten known, conceptually distinct ways to do it (including yours), fleshed out in hundreds of concrete models. The problem is that all of them require speculative new physics, additions to the core models that we have already experimentally verified. Nobody can declare that a specific one of these models is true, in the absence of any independent evidence.

It's kind of like we're all sitting around trying to find the six-digit password for a safe. If you walk by and say "well, obviously it *could* be 927583", without any further evidence, that's technically true. But you have not cracked the safe. The problem of baryogenesis isn't analogous to coming up with *any* six-digit number, that's easy. The problem is that we don't know which one is relevant, which mechanism actually exists in our universe.

What physicists investigating these questions actually do involves trying to link these models to things we can measure, or coming up with simple models that explain multiple puzzles at once. For example, one way to test a model with primordial black holes is to compute the amount heavy enough to live until the present day, in which case you can go looking for them. Or, if they were created by some new physics, you could look for that new physics. Yet another strand is to note that if enough primordial black holes still are around today, they could be the dark matter, so you could try to get both baryogenesis and dark matter right simultaneously. All of this involves a lot of reading, math, and simulation.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99369/discussion-on-answer-by-knzhou-why-is-matter-antimatter-asymmetry-surprising-if).

Comment: It sounds like the OP asked "Why is X surprising, when I can construct a perfectly reasonable explanation for it?". And your response is "There are a bunch of possible explanations for it." That doesn't directly answer the OP's question. It sounds like the direct answer is "The existence of an imbalance isn't itself surprising ... its just that we don't specifically know why it exists" ... In your analogy, we aren't surprised by the assertion that the IS something under the magician's hat, ... we just don't know what that thing is.

Comment: Deleted a further round of extended discussion in comments. If anyone wants to have a *conversation* here, take it to chat.

Comment: So the real question is: _why has it been so difficult to find evidence for what the real and 'correct' mechanism is?_

Comment: @The_Sympathizer The answer is simply that the history of the universe is an excellent eraser. Roughly, everything ends up in thermal equilibrium for a long time, so the only features that survive are "relics" such as the baryon number itself. This is also why I emphasized "explaining multiple puzzles at once"... it's quite easy, even typical, to end up with a hypothesis that is completely untestable if you don't.

Comment: @knzhou : Yep. Just like a lot of other types of historical study in other fields (like biology, human history.). The information is gone, dissipated, entropized, unrecoverable.

Answer (score 33):

### Locality

The random walk would be expected to create different (opposing) asymetries in different regions, including regions that are distant enough to not affect each other. If *this* would be the main cause of asymetry, then we'd expect it to cause a predominance of matter in some areas of the observable universe and a predominance of antimatter in other areas of the observable universe.

However, we observe a global, universal predominance of matter that seems uniform across all the observable universe; as any boundary between matter and antimatter regions would create observable effects that don't seem to exist.

Comment: If "black hole baryogenesis" was most common soon after the big bang then I would expect the results to be uniform today. Basically I am imagining that the rate of baryogenesis is much lower today than in the past because there are fewer black holes (because the universe has become less dense).

Comment: @Livid "the rate of baryogenesis is much lower today than in the past" is a key assumption here that's IMHO *not* directly inferrable from the fact that the unverse was more hot/more dense, but seems like it should have a solid true/false answer  though I'm not competent to say which it is.

Comment: Since you think we can observe this, I want to know how we can observe the matter/antimatterness of a galaxy outside the local group.

Comment: @Joshua the gist is that while interstellar space is very, very sparse, if in two neighbouring galaxies (and their surrounding regions of space) one was predominantly matter and the other was antimatter, then on the boundary between the "matter region" and "antimatter region", even if that boundary (the not-a-galaxy "empty" space) is as sparse as it gets, that boundary region is unavoidably sufficiently large so that the annihilation events and their energy signature would be frequent enough to be clearly observable and unusual enough so that they would not get confused with something else.

Comment: Are you willing to say the same for interactions between galaxy groups? Interaction between groups falls off pretty fast.

Comment: @Livid Black holes have nothing to do with *absolute* density; it's about density *gradients*. When inflation ended, energy density was huge, yes - but it was also essentially the same everywhere. There's no reason to expect there were more black holes than today, especially the kind that doesn't evaporate in a very short time. Keep in mind that charge is conserved - the escaping -1 of a single electron is balanced by an extra +1 on the black hole - which of course both makes the black hole repel further positrons and attract electrons, and when Hawking radiation is emitted, it is not neutral.

Comment: @Luaan See my first sentence about kugelblitz in the early universe. The way I imagined it, first there was an energy only universe, then some black holes formed from that, then the black holes produced matter and antimatter and one "randomly" became dominant like shown in the simulation.

Comment: @Livid You still need density gradients to form black holes. The universe is *extremely* uniform. But even if black holes somehow formed in large quantities, and yet small masses (to readily "evaporate"), and even if all matter and anti-matter formed as Hawking radiation (no reason to believe that either), you would need to conserve charge. That's a huge problem, because protons are much more massive than electrons. You wouldn't get a world of X protons and X electrons, you would get a world of X positrons and X electrons. To get a matter-universe, you need something that prefers matter.

Comment: @Livid I've actually written an answer that explores all that (and attempts to show by analogy how Hawking radiation *actually* works, assuming it exists in the first place), but it turned out a bit too long so I dropped it. But the big point is that 1) the universe seems massively dominated by matter, despite the large distances; there's no blobs of matter and blobs of antimatter, even on the largest observable scales, 2) charge must be conserved, 3) Hawking radiation is not in any way like "half of a virtual particle pair falls into a black hole", 4) black holes need density *gradients*

Comment: @Luaan As mentioned in the other answers "black hole baryogenesis" is an accepted process consistent with standard physics. Are you disagreeing with that?

Comment: @Livid No. If the early universe was full of microscopic primordial black holes, their evaporation could be the source of all the matter around us (But that's a big if! You need a way for those black holes to form). But that's not what you asked about in your question, at least originally.

Comment: @Luaan In the original question I assumed the blackholes were kugelblitz.

Comment: @Livid In what way does that change anything?

Comment: @Luaan You said "You need a way for those black holes to form". The mechanism is however kugelblitz form.

Answer (score 21):

Your simulation randomly creates a single particle that is either type 1 or type 2. If these two types are charged, then either of these two creation processes violates conservation of charge. Charge conservation is an absolute law of physics as far as we know, and this includes processes like the formation and evaporation of black holes.

The OP clarified in a comment:

> Both particles are created, but one gets sucked into the black hole. The other stays outside. So the charge should be conserved.

Sucking a particle into a black hole doesn't mean that it's as if the particle has never existed. Its mass-energy, charge, and angular momentum are still present in the black hole. This is an example of the universality of charge conservation as a law of physics.

In your simulation, let's say that the particles represented by the black curve on your graph are electrons. Then the universe in your simulation has accumulated a big surplus of positively charged black holes. These positively charged black holes do not (on the average) emit electrically neutral Hawking radiation. By the time they evaporate completely, they will have emitted positively charged particles such as positrons in a quantity that exactly equals the number of positive charges they consumed. (I'm making these statements as if we knew for sure that Hawking radiation operated in a certain way. Actually we have no direct evidence, and the methods of semiclassical gravity have never been compared against observation in any way, so we can't really be sure that they work.)

You may want to look at the Sakharov conditions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryogenesis#GUT_Baryogenesis_under_Sakharov_conditions

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99370/discussion-on-answer-by-ben-crowell-why-is-matter-antimatter-asymmetry-surprisin).

Answer (score 5):

Matter and antimatter isn't created one at a time at random. To fix your simulation, you'd need to always create an electron at the same time you create a positron.

Does adding a black hole break that symmetry? Definitely not. Charge is still conserved - the positron that "falls" into the black hole doesn't just disappear - it alters the charge, angular momentum etc. of the entire black hole. So if the black hole absorbs an electron, it becomes slightly more negatively charged. The black hole isn't just as likely to absorb an electron as it is to absorb a positron  - every unbalancing of the charge means that differently charged particles are attracted differently. If you black hole somehow managed to consume a billion electrons at once, it will *repel* electrons, while *attracting* positrons. The disbalance would quickly disappear.

But that's not how Hawking radiation works anyway (assuming it actually exists). There's no particle-anti-particle pair that gets created near the even horizon of the black hole, of which one is randomly created in a way that makes it fall into the hole, while the other escapes. If this was the right picture, Hawking radiation would be emitted in *all* kinds of warped space times, including the Earth's. The so-called virtual particles are disturbations in the underlying quantum fields that *aren't* particles. A real particle is a stable wave packet in the field which self-propagates, and if you ignore interactios with other fields, doesn't ever go away; it has a definite mass, electric charge etc.. Virtual particles are more like the water ripples you get when you throw a stone in a pond. A virtual electron doesn't have the electron's mass, or its charge, or anything else. It's not an electron that annihilates with a positron too fast to be observable - it isn't a particle at all. Sometimes, people confuse things like "2 photons -> 1 electron + 1 positron -> 2 photons" with virtual particles. There's no useful similarity between the two. A black hole is kind of like a hole in a drum skin. Its presence means that some vibrational modes aren't allowed, while others that wouldn't be allowed in an intact drum... are.

Of course, positrons aren't the only positively charged particle in the universe. Could the radiation be in the form of protons? Not really. Protons are *really really massive* compared to electrons and positrons. Even if you had a black hole small enough to have Hawking radiation energetic enough to produce protons, you would expect a thousand positrons for every proton produced, even assuming positrons and protons worked exactly the same way (which they don't). And of course, you would still expect anti-protons to be produced in the same quantities - the end result is still a universe with no matter or anti-matter.

This also means that it's actually pretty hard to make matter out of Hawking radiation! If you believe the popular description of Hawking radiation and virtual particles, you should expect that a bigger black hole produces a lot more radiation than a small black hole. The "spontaneous pair formation" should be the same in all of space-time, so all else equal, a bigger black hole should "capture" more of the pairs than a smaller black hole; if we ignore all the effects like charge and gravity, you should expect that the pair production would correspond to the surface area of the black hole (the event horizon).

But this isn't the case at all - smaller black holes are expected to emit far more radiation than large black holes. Not only that, but larger black holes emit far longer wavelengths (and thus less energetic particles, almost exclusively photons and perhaps neutrinos) than small black holes. Stellar mass black holes are way too massive to produce something like an electron - even Earth-mass black hole is *way* too much (about seven orders of magnitude too much). Needless to say, you should expect protons from even smaller black holes, and in vastly lower quantities than any electrons; and for a non-charged black hole, you will get roughly as many electrons as positrons. The symmetry is still there, because in the end, you're not randomly consuming one of a pair of spontaneously formed particles - you're distorting the oscillations in the electric quantum field, and the result depends on what the value of the field was in the first place.

To explain the dominance of matter in the universe, you need something that prefers matter. Even if mere statistical fluke was enough to explain the matter dominance, you wouldn't expect the universe to be *uniformly* made out of matter. You should expect pockets of matter, next to pockets of anti-matter. But that would be very obvious in our surveys, even from very far away - the interface between the matter-pocket and the anti-matter-pocket would glow like crazy. We don't see that.

But we've actually managed to find *one* thing in the universe that treats matter and anti-matter differently - the symmetry isn't perfect. This is the weak nuclear force, and physicists are very excited to learn more about this fundamental force which has been a bit neglected so far; and especially about its connection with the relatively recently confirmed Higgs field. I'm not going to elaborate, since this is already way too long :)

We still have one important thing left. You assume that if there was a lot of energy density in the early universe, this must have caused black holes to form. This is a common misunderstanding - black holes do not form as a result of high density of matter or energy. They require a density *gradient*. The distinction doesn't matter much when you're talking about the black holes we observe - you're essentially comparing the near-vacuum's energy density to a massively compacted stellar-masses of matter. But while the early universe, before baryogenesis, had a very high energy density, it was also incredibly uniform - it was (and still is) very, very flat. There was no "sloping" of the spacetime, and no black holes. You would first need significant deviations, localised pockets of low energy density - but we see in the cosmic background radiation that the universe was *extremely* uniform (at the point where it became largely transparent to radiation).

Comment: _"Matter and antimatter isn't created one at a time at random. To fix your simulation, you'd need to always create an electron at the same time you create a positron."_ That is what happens in hawking radiation, which my simulation models.

Comment: "To explain the dominance of matter in the universe, you need something that prefers matter. ". I think you missed an essential part of the question. Whatever is left is called "matter". That's anthropocentric nomenclature. If by random chance the other sort of matter would have survived, _that_ would have been called matter instead. There's no need for a preference, just symmetry breaking.

Comment: @MSalters You need a preference to explain why the symmetry breaks the same way *everywhere* in the universe, rather than in random matter and antimatter patches.

Comment: @chris That is why I guessed matter got "locked in" as the dominant species in the very dense high energy environment soon after the big bang. The rate of baryogenesis should be much lower now. While it is possible to get local regions dominated by antimatter via this method it should be very rare because all the local matter needs to be annihilated first.

Comment: @Livid There are parts of the universe that are causually disconnected from one another- i.e. they haven't had any chance to mix with one another since the Big Bang (or the end of inflation, in inflationary models). Anyway if you're positing that random chance caused the baryon imbalance we see today, there's no point in bringing up black holes at all- it's at least as likely to happen by random chance without black holes.

Comment: @Chris No I am not proposing "random chance caused the baryon imbalance we see today." I am saying **a baryon imbalance is guaranteed if you accept matter-antimatter pair production/annihilation and hawking radiation**. Which species ends up dominant (and called "matter") is arbitrary given our knowledge of the system. Call that aspect "random" if you want.

Comment: @Livid A local baryon imbalance on some scale is guaranteed *just* by random chance: i.e. the density of baryon number is not uniformly zero. Do the same random walk just with particles leaving and entering a volume of space and you'll get similar results.

Comment: @Chris _"Do the same random walk just with particles leaving and entering a volume of space and you'll get similar results. "_ You will have to code it up to demonstrate that because this makes no sense to me. I know for certain that I will get ~50% matter and 50% antimatter in the volume. Not a dominating species.

Comment: @Chris By "baryon imbalance" i am talking about nearly all the baryons are of one species (ie matter), not 51-49% or something like that. A near equal amount of matter and antimatter is unstable and I would never expect to observe it. My question is why physicists apparently do expect to see that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99444/discussion-between-chris-and-livid).

Comment: @MSalters Not really. If matter and anti-matter switched places, we would just call anti-matter matter. It doesn't change the argument - you still need something that preferes one or the other. Symmetry breaking would be enough if you assumed what Livid assumed - that every individual electron immediatelly annihilates with a positron, if there is any, and vice versa. But we know that isn't the case, because the universal speed limit exists, and you should expect volumes where matter is dominant, and volumes where anti-matter is dominant -  which we don't observe.

Comment: @Luaan The immediate annihilation is not necessary for the domination to arise. See my latest update where I make the probability of annihilation a function of the number of particles (same is seen if I use only the number of particles "anti" to the one just generated). And I also wonder whether the very early universe was be so small that the annihilation could be practically instant.

Comment: @Livid It's not about the time, it's about the distance - particles coming close enough to annihilate at all. The point is that as separations increase, you would expect blobs of matter and anti-matter to form, rather than a uniform matter-ness or anti-matterness. You're still assuming there's a global pool of matter and anti-matter.

Comment: @Luaan If you want tell me what you want simulated that makes sense to you like Chris did. We need to figure out a way that doesn't end up with me calculating trajectories and doing leapfrog integration, etc though. It needs to be a simple proof of concept.

Comment: @Livid In the end, it's very simple. Run 100 simulations. Instead of averaging them out, count how many end up matter dominated, and how many anti-matter dominated. That's your expectation for how causally disconnected parts of the universe should look on average. You will find that the universe ends up in a mix of matter and anti-matter blobs, something we do not observe in reality.

Comment: @Luaan You can find that and more in my discussion with Chris [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99444/discussion-between-chris-and-livid).  As I have said a couple times now: We do not live in the average of many universes, we observe one instance of a universe. So it is incorrect to compare what is predicted on average to our observations. It is unsurprising to me that the average result is not observed in reality. I think it is confusing because the calculations for the average have no logical flaw and have the same units as the individual instances, but they mean different things.

Comment: @Livid Exactly, we do not live in the average of many universes. But that's what you're simulating. What I'm proposing is that you simulate many individual causally disconnected *patches* of our universe. You're still assuming that every electron had enough time to annihilate with every positron in existence. But how, if the speed of light is finite? How large do you assume the universe to be at the point where baryogenesis stopped? How fast was it expanding? You're assuming that what happened in one place must have happened *exactly the same* in all the places in the early universe.

Comment: @Luaan I am specifically not trying to simulate an average universe and compare it to our universe, but that is what you just literally asked me to do _"how causally disconnected parts of the universe should look on average"._ And I don't see where I'm assuming "every electron had enough time to annihilate every positron" in Chris' model. It assumes they interact at a rate proportional to the product of the number of each in existence: m*n1*n2. Now you are claiming that there is some other effect due to I'm not really sure what that will cancel out the imbalance. How can I add this?

Comment: @Livid I'm not sure what's so hard to grasp here. Space is big. You're assuming just because there is a positron and an electron, they will annihilate. That is not the case - they need to approach each other first. Most of the stuff in the universe never got a chance to interact in any way. So in your model, you should assume you get volumes of space where matter dominates, and volumes of space where anti-matter dominates. They cannot reach each other to annihilate each other. The imbalance is there to stay.

Comment: @Luaan _"You're assuming just because there is a positron and an electron, they will annihilate."_ I disagree, however the model (I am talking about the poissoin(m*n0*n1) model) does assume that any positron and electron can eventually annihilate each other. _" in your model, you should assume you get volumes of space where matter dominates, and volumes of space where anti-matter dominates. "_ This would be assuming the very thing in question... Why would I assume something that is not observed in reality? That is something that needs to be deduced from some principles, not assumed itself.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the answers to this old question, I don't see the basic statistical argument: the matter-antimatter asymmetry is just *too big* to be explained by a random walk.

Consider that a random walk of $N$ steps tends to end up about $\sqrt N$ steps away from its starting point. Similarly, a Poisson process (in which all events are independent) which produces on average $N$ successes will have an uncertainty around that average of around $\sqrt N$.

The observable universe contains roughly $10^{80}$ baryons. If we imagine that this is a statistical fluctuation in a process which has zero intrinsic preference for matter over antimatter, that process would have had to occur roughly $10^{160}$ times.  Suppose each such annihilation eventually produces two photons: those photons would now contribute to the cosmic microwave background. But we *know* the density of the CMB.  Our universe's ratio of baryons to photons is about $10^{-9}$, not $10^{-80}$.

There is already CP violation (that is, matter-antimatter asymmetry) in the Standard Model. The problem is that the known $CP$ violation is too small to explain the matter dominance we are made of. But the missing CP violation is a matter of a factor of $10^{4}$ or so, not a factor of a billion.

Comment: You are dealing in averages, though. We do not observe an average universe, we observe one instance of the universe. The simulations show that while *on average* (over time and/or the "multiverse") we should expect symmetry from the standard assumptions, it is actually very rare to be in a universe where you would observe this.

Comment: Re "the simulations show": please provide a citation and we can discuss this further.

Comment: I'm referring to the simulations I put in the OP. Eg, these results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jo4kc.png

Comment: In your simulations, do the annihilated massive particles produce photons? I would be interested in your baryon-to-photon ratio.

Comment: It is a 1D toy model, meant to demonstrate the principle that average expected effects do not correspond to observed effects when we observe n = 1 universe. What it does is update each step, where each step is a new baryon being created via black hole baryogenesis. During that same step some number of particles annihilate proportional to the product of matter*antimatter particles. So I guess you can say it assumes photon number >> baryon number at all times. It would be trivial to compute photons generated using this model, but the rate of absorption by matter would add an entirely new aspect.

Comment: By absorption I mean the energy is stored in larger nuclei, covalent bonds, and such. But once we consider that we also have a situation where high energy photons can be re-emitted as multiple low energy photons.

Comment: You can neglect absorption for an order-of-magnitude estimate. But the algorithm you're describing is very different from any model of baryogenesis, in a way that I can't really describe in a comment.

Comment: This is not at all a quantitative model. It is a 1D qualitative model. What it says is that the people with funding to work out quantitative models need to look at individual simulation runs, *not* average a bunch of them together. Because that can give the exactly opposite impression of what we should expect to observe according to current theory. As of now, there is nothing surprising about have way more matter than antimatter. That is precisely what we expect to see. If there is a more complicated model that says otherwise then great. But I bet that'll require quite a bit of fine tuning.

Comment: More complicated models predict a small (but nonzero) baryon asymmetry, associated with CP violation in the  Standard Model. If I were going to dig into the literature, I would start with the relevant chapter in a recent Particle Data Group report, and its bibliography.

Comment: Look closer and you will find that is what the model predicts *on average*, which is decidedly *not* what we expect to observe according to the theory.

Comment: In analogy, the average person has slightly off from one ovary. But if we look at individual instances of people the vast majority have either two or zero ovaries. It is an error to confuse the two even if they have the same units.