# Charged black holes and the matter antimatter imbalance

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, big-bang, antimatter, baryogenesis

After the big bang, could it be that lots of charged primordial black holes began to form? Would this make it more likely for oppositely charged particles to fall in, and thus cause the matter/antimatter imbalance we see today? And when particles are created by Hawking radiation, would the same charged particle be more likely to escape?

Comment: knzhou wrote a good answer about this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/505692

Comment: Thankyou for the interesting link